# Mudar o tipo de uma coluna em varias tabelas no SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

Possuo um banco de dados com 41 tabelas, em todas as tabelas eu possuo uma coluna em comum ao qual gostaria de atribuir outro dataType. No meu caso a coluna atualmente esta como varchar(255) e gostaria de mudar para small dataTime, contudo gostaria de evitar ter que ir de tabela por tabela fazendo esta alteração. Existe alguma forma de fazer isto ? Nas pesquisas que tenho feito não achei nada didático referente a mudança de tipo de uma coluna em varias tabelas de forma rápida, tendo em vista que comecei a estudar banco de dados e SQL Server recentemente.

Comment: pode criar uma `function` ou uma `procedure` que faça isso, você que escolhe

Comment: @Tmilitino Irei fazer algumas pesquisas a respeito de functions e procedures. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `CURSOR` para percorrer as tabelas que possuem aquela coluna e executar o `ALTER TABLE` para mudar o tipo:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(50),
        @tabela VARCHAR(50),
        @coluna VARCHAR(50) = 'NOME_COLUNA';

DECLARE cursor_alteracao CURSOR FOR   
  SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + c.table_schema + '.' + c.table_name + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @coluna + 'SMALLDATETIME'
    FROM information_schema.columns c
   WHERE c.column_name = @coluna;

OPEN cursor_alteracao;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_alteracao
INTO @schema, @tabela;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
  EXEC('ALTER TABLE ' + @schema + '.' + @tabela + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @coluna + ' SMALLDATETIME');

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_alteracao   
  INTO @schema, @tabela;
END   
CLOSE cursor_alteracao;  
DEALLOCATE cursor_alteracao;
```